# Changing the position of alert after user scrolls down the navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

In my React app, I have an alert that is positioned just below the navbar. When the user scrolls down the navbar I want to change the position of the alert to top = 0 keeping it fixed, so that the user can see the alert from all the scroll positions.

alert.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
// import AlertContext from '../context/alert/alertContext'

const Alert = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: '50px',
        position: 'fixed',
        width: '100vw'
      }}
    >
      {
        // props.alert &&
        <div
          // ref={alertRef}
          className={`alert alert-${props.alert.type} alert-dismissible fade show`}
          role='alert'
        >
          {props.alert.msg}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Alert
```

I tried using the useEffect, useState and useRef hook. I tried setting up an event listener which would chnage the state(posiiton top) of the alert component after the user scrolls down a given height but the alert component was not changing position. Also if i could get the height of the navbar it would be useful. So please help.